# How to compare two arrays and returns the list of deleted/updated/inserted elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two set of object arrays . As below , I want to compare these two arrays and get the deleted/updated/inserted list of elements as a new array.
How to achieve this properly in JavaScript. Is there any API available by default?

```
[
    {
        user_id: 1,
        user_name: "XXXX",
        location:"India"

    },
    {
        user_id: 2,
        user_name: "YYYY",
        location:"India"

    },
    {
        user_id: 3,
        user_name: "ZZZZ",
        location:"India"

    }

]

[
    {
        user_id: 1,
        user_name: "XXXX",
        location:"United States"

    },
    {
        user_id: 3,
        user_name: "ZZZZ",
        location:"India"

    },
    {
        user_id: 4,
        user_name: "AAAA",
        location:"Germany"

    },
    {
        user_id: 5,
        user_name: "BBBB",
        location:"England"

    }

]
```

Comment: did you try lodash?

Comment: No . I am trying to write plain for loop.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the user_id is unique in each array, and matches in both array. Not sure if the output is what you expect, if not, please describe in details.

```
var arr1 = [{
  user_id: 1,
  user_name: "XXXX",
  location: "India"
}, {
  user_id: 2,
  user_name: "YYYY",
  location: "India"
}, {
  user_id: 3,
  user_name: "ZZZZ",
  location: "India"
}];

var arr2 = [{
  user_id: 1,
  user_name: "XXXX",
  location: "United States"
}, {
  user_id: 3,
  user_name: "ZZZZ",
  location: "India"
}, {
  user_id: 4,
  user_name: "AAAA",
  location: "Germany"
}, {
  user_id: 5,
  user_name: "BBBB",
  location: "England"
}]

var keys1 = {};
var keys2 = {};

var inserted = [];
var updated = [];
var deleted = [];

arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  keys1[item.user_id] = item;
});

arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  keys2[item.user_id] = item;
});

arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  var obj = keys2[item.user_id]
  if (!obj) {
    deleted.push(item);
  } else {
    if (obj.username !== item.username || obj.location !== item.location) {
      updated.push(item);
    }
  }
});

arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!keys1[item.user_id]) {
    inserted.push(item);
  }
});


console.log('inserted', inserted);
console.log('updated', updated);
console.log('deleted', deleted);
```

Comment: I like this code. With some abstraction, someone could wrap it in a function that lets a user export whichever of the result arrays (or merges of said arrays) suit their needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library such as lodash to compare arrays using their comparators.

`_.difference` can be passed an array and a second array of values to compare against it, and it will return the difference between the two.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference

If you need to drill down into the objects within the arrays, you would need to use one of the more sophisticated difference methods, such as `_.differencewith()` which would allow you to pass a comparator function.

In that function, you can pass corresponding objects from each array and recursively compare them.